# C++ Segmentation fault when working with <vector> and <fstream>

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, fstream, ostream

I was working with 3D vectors and everything worked perfectly. When I added  and worked with ofstream files Segmentation Fault appeared.
I don't understand the problem at all.
The following code doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

std::vector < std::vector < std::vector <float> > > hand;


int main(){

//First Part
std::ofstream file;
file.open("test.csv");
file << "Hello World!";
file.close();

//Second Part
hand.reserve(20);
for (int i=0; i<hand.capacity(); i++){
    hand[i].reserve(4);
}

return 0;
}
```

If you comment one of the parts the code will work perfectly. The Segmentation fault appears when you want to work with them at the same time.

It is also important to notice that the code can work if instead of:

```
hand.reserve(20);
```

we use a number below 8:

```
hand.reserve(7); //or lower
```

My question is: Why is the code not working when I use them at the same time? What can I do to fix it? Do you have any explanation about this particular case?

I'll have to implement this in a much bigger code, so it would be good to know the root cause and avoid it in the next cases.

Comment: Have you debugged your application and looked for any 0-values?

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
hand.reserve(20);
```

to

```
hand.resize(20);
```

`reserve` will only change vector *capacity* to store data, without creating any actual objects. Thus using `reserve` you will get still empty vector, that is able to accept 20 new values without reallocation. `capacity()` is not the same as `size()` it returns amount of elements that vector has already allocated memory for, and it can be bigger than `size()` that returns actual element count.

Answer (score 2):

You can't start using elements (i.e. `hand[i].`) just because you've reserved space for them... they haven't been constructed.  You should use `resize(20)` to not only request the memory but also initialise the elements of `hand`, after which you can `reserve` or `resize` the contained containers....

Answer (score 1):

`reserve` only increases the capacity of the vector, not its actual size.

However in your loop when you do `hand[i]` you are accessing the vector's items as if it had been actually resized, but in fact those items don't exist yet. Hence the segfault.

You may want to replace the first `reserve` call with `resize` (and perhaps the other subsequent `reserve` calls too).